# PyMonogo + Gevent1.0 ReplicaSetClient never returns

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gevent

I am trying to connect to a mongo server using mongo engine with gevent.  The [pymongo documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gevent.html) says that gevent support is pretty straight forward.  Since gevent released 1.0 the example linked to above doesn't work with PyMongo MongoReplicaSetClient.

If you open up a python prompt and try the code in the example things for fine:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket()
from pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client import MongoReplicaSetClient
rsc = MongoReplicaSetClient('mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019', replicaSet='repl0', use_greenlets=True)
print rsc
MongoReplicaSetClient([u'localhost:27017'])
```

I saved this code as a file called connection.py.  If I run this file from the command line it works fine.

```
$python connection.py
MongoReplicaSetClient([u'localhost:27017'])
```

But if I try to import this module it never returns.  Eventually I have to press Ctrl-C:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 21 2013, 14:51:47) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ecs.db.mongo import connection
^CKeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ecs/db/mongo/connection.py", line 15, in <module>
    c = MongoReplicaSetClient('mongodb://localhost/ecs', replicaSet='ecsReplicaSet', use_greenlets=True)
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 742, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1179, in refresh
    res, connection_pool, ping_time = self.__is_master(host)
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1056, in __is_master
    sock_info = connection_pool.get_socket()
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 339, in get_socket
    sock_info, from_pool = self.connect(pair), False
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 265, in connect
    sock = self.create_connection(pair)
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 237, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 621, in getaddrinfo
    return get_hub().resolver.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socktype, proto, flags)
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/resolver_thread.py", line 34, in getaddrinfo
    return self.pool.apply_e(self.expected_errors, _socket.getaddrinfo, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/threadpool.py", line 222, in apply_e
    success, result = self.spawn(wrap_errors, expected_errors, function, args, kwargs).get()
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/event.py", line 226, in get
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "/home/daniels/.virtualenvs/parlant-ecs-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 331, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm not certain what I am missing, but there seems to be a problem with PyMongo and gevent 1.0.  This worked fine with gevent 0.13.8.

**Edit:** I just found [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-607) with pymongo that explains the problem and offers a few work arrounds.